# Can't update my services references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, visual-studio-2012, glimpse

Everything works great if I uninstalled Glimpse.

However; if I installed Glimpse, I can't update my services references.

I get the following error:

[image]

The translation is (sorry, I don't have permission to change the language of VS 2012):

> Warning of the personalised tool: Cant import wsdl:portType. Details:
>   An exception occurred when trying to execute an extension of the WSDL
>   import:System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Can't load the file or assembly 'Glimpse.Core, Version=1.8.2.0'
>   .......

After that warning I get these warnings:

[image]

And after that, an error saying that the code of the Service could not be generated.

Any ideas of what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The first error message says that it can't find the file, maybe because you haven't imported or added to the solution (Or it is in some admin protected folder maybe?) it yet, the other two errors are caused because they need wsdl:portType to work.